# Valid values for FIXED_LEVELS option with GDALContourGenerateEx

Tags: python, gdal, contour, gdal-contour

We are creating contour polygons using the gdal Python library. I can create a shapefile with these options, vector_options = [f'LEVEL_INTERVAL={contour_interval}', 'ID_FIELD=0', 'ELEV_FIELD_MIN=1', 'POLYGONIZE=YES'] but we want to create intervals under 1 to plot rainfall levels.

Can decimal values be used in with the FIXED_LEVELS option?

When I tried using these options a shapefile is created but the rainfall values are all missing.  Here are the options I tried:
vector_options = [f'FIXED_LEVELS=0.1, 1.0, 2.0, 6, 12, 24, 48, 60', 'ID_FIELD=0', 'ELEV_FIELD_MIN=0.1', 'POLYGONIZE=YES']